# Binary-CrossEntropy - Works on Keras But Not on Lasagne?

Tags: theano, keras, lasagne, cross-entropy

Im using the same convolutional neural network structure on Keras and Lasagne. 
Right now, i just changed to  a simple network to see if it changed anything, but it didnt.

On Keras it works fine, it outputs values between 0 and 1 with a good accuracy.
On lasagne, the values dont come mostly wrong. It seems the output is the same as the input.

Basically : It outputs and train fine on keras. But not on my lasagne Version

Structure On Lasagne :

```
def structure(w=5, h=5):
    try:

        input_var = T.tensor4('inputs')
        target_var = T.bmatrix('targets')

        network = lasagne.layers.InputLayer(shape=(None, 1, h, w), input_var=input_var)

        network = lasagne.layers.Conv2DLayer(
            network, num_filters=64, filter_size=(3, 3), stride=1, pad=0,
            nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.rectify,
            W=lasagne.init.GlorotUniform())

        network = lasagne.layers.Conv2DLayer(
            network, num_filters=64, filter_size=(3, 3), stride=1, pad=0,
            nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.rectify,
            W=lasagne.init.GlorotUniform())

        network = lasagne.layers.MaxPool2DLayer(network, pool_size=(2, 2), stride=None, pad=(0, 0), ignore_border=True)

        network = lasagne.layers.DenseLayer(
            lasagne.layers.dropout(network, p=0.5),
            num_units=256,
            nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.rectify, W=lasagne.init.GlorotUniform())

        network = lasagne.layers.DenseLayer(
            lasagne.layers.dropout(network, p=0.5),
            num_units=1,
            nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.sigmoid)

        print  "...Output", lasagne.layers.get_output_shape(network)

        return network, input_var, target_var

    except Exception as inst:
        print ("Failure to Build NN !", inst.message, (type(inst)), (inst.args), (inst))

    return None
```

On Keras :

```
def getModel(w,h):
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
    from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
    from keras.optimizers import SGD

    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='valid', input_shape=(1, h, w)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, border_mode='valid'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    #
    model.add(Flatten())
    #
    model.add(Dense(256))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    model.add(Dense(128))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    #
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

    sgd = SGD(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd')

    return model
```

And to train on Keras..

```
model.fit(x, y, batch_size=512, nb_epoch=500, verbose=2, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True, show_accuracy=True)
```

And to train and predict on Lasagne :

To Train :

```
prediction = lasagne.layers.get_output(network)

loss = lasagne.objectives.binary_crossentropy(prediction, target_var)
loss = loss.mean()

params = lasagne.layers.get_all_params(network, trainable=True)

# updates = lasagne.updates.sgd(loss, params, learning_rate=learning_rate)
updates = lasagne.updates.nesterov_momentum(loss_or_grads=loss, params=params, learning_rate=learning_rate, momentum=momentum_rho)

#
test_prediction = lasagne.layers.get_output(network, deterministic=True)

test_prediction = lasagne.layers.get_output(network, deterministic=True)
test_loss = lasagne.objectives.binary_crossentropy(test_prediction, target_var)
test_loss = test_loss.mean()

# Accuracy
test_acc = lasagne.objectives.binary_accuracy(test_prediction, target_var)
test_acc = test_acc.mean()

train_fn = theano.function([input_var, target_var], loss, updates=updates)
val_fn = theano.function([input_var, target_var], [test_loss, test_acc])
```

**And im using these  iterators which i hope isnt the cause of it.. Maybe it is?**

```
def iterate_minibatches_getOutput(self, inputs, batchsize):
    for start_idx in range(0, len(inputs) - batchsize + 1, batchsize):
        excerpt = slice(start_idx, start_idx + batchsize)
        yield inputs[excerpt]

def iterate_minibatches(self, inputs, targets, batchsize, shuffle=False):
    assert len(inputs) == len(targets)
    if shuffle:
        indices = np.arange(len(inputs))
        np.random.shuffle(indices)
    for start_idx in range(0, len(inputs) - batchsize + 1, batchsize):
        if shuffle:
            excerpt = indices[start_idx:start_idx + batchsize]
        else:
            excerpt = slice(start_idx, start_idx + batchsize)
        yield inputs[excerpt], targets[excerpt]
```

To Predict :

```
test_prediction = lasagne.layers.get_output(self.network, deterministic=True)
predict_fn = theano.function([self.input_var], test_prediction)


index = 0
for batch in self.iterate_minibatches_getOutput(inputs=submission_feature_x, batchsize=self.batch_size):
    inputs = batch
    y = predict_fn(inputs)
    start = index * self.batch_size
    end = (index + 1) * self.batch_size
    predictions[index * self.batch_size:self.batch_size * (index + 1)] = y
    index += 1

print "debug -->", predictions[0:10]
print "debug max ---->", np.max(predictions)
print "debug min ----->", np.min(predictions)
```

This Prints :

```
debug --> [[ 0.3252553 ]
 [ 0.3252553 ]
 [ 0.3252553 ]
 [ 0.3252553 ]
 [ 0.3252553 ]
 [ 0.3252553 ]
 [ 0.3252553 ]
 [ 0.3252553 ]
 [ 0.3252553 ]
 [ 0.32534513]]
debug max ----> 1.0
debug min -----> 0.0
```

The results are totally wrong.
However, what confuses me, is that it outputs fine on keras.

Also, the validation acc never changes:

```
Epoch 2 of 30 took 9.5846s
  Training loss:                0.22714619
  Validation loss:              0.17278196
  Validation accuracy:          95.85454545 %
Epoch 3 of 30 took 9.6437s
  Training loss:                0.22646923
  Validation loss:              0.17249792
  Validation accuracy:          95.85454545 %
Epoch 4 of 30 took 9.6464s
  Training loss:                0.22563262
  Validation loss:              0.17235395
  Validation accuracy:          95.85454545 %
Epoch 5 of 30 took 10.5069s
  Training loss:                0.22464556
  Validation loss:              0.17226825
  Validation accuracy:          95.85454545 %
...
```

Please Help!
What am i doing wrong?

---

These are the shapes being used:

```
x_train.shape  (102746, 1, 17, 17)
y_train.shape  (102746, 1)
x_val.shape  (11416, 1, 17, 17)
y_val.shape  (11416, 1)
```

Comment: I dont understand the -1 vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

THe problem was :

```
target_var = T.bmatrix('targets')
```

Should be :

```
target_var = T.fmatrix('targets')
```

Also, the learning rate was too low.

And on the Keras Script, there was another error :

```
sgd = SGD(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd')
```

Should be :

```
sgd = SGD(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd)
```